# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown for static method but not for static member

Tags: java, exception, dnsjava

Working with the [dnsjava](http://www.dnsjava.org/) library, I've encountered a frustrating and confusing problem where I can call `Type.A` properly but calling `Type.value(str)` throws a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

```
System.out.println(org.xbill.DNS.Type.A);    // works

if (org.xbill.DNS.Type.value(type) == -1) {  // throws NoClassDefFoundError
  /* logic */
}
```

This code is being executed from a `jar` and other classes in the jar use the library correctly.

Why and how could this be happening? How can I debug this further?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Jon Skeet was correct. A friend showed me how to use `javap -c` and I changed the value to something more distinct, Type.AAAA, which has a value of 28:

```
878: getstatic       #116; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
881: bipush  28
```

Comment: Does adding the `-verbose:class` command line argument reveal something? Often when you get this error, it's a different class that is missing, one that is referenced by the class you want to load.

Comment: Could you show the full stacktrace of the NoClassDefFoundError?  This error is thrown in at least three different situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're missing the `dnsjava` library at execution time.

That doesn't matter for `Type.A` because that's a *constant* - the value is being pulled out by the compiler and embedded directly into your code, as if you'd specified it as an integer literal. It doesn't *need* the library to be present at execution time. That's clearly not the case when you call a method though.

Comment: You're right, Type.A is an `int` and therefore the value can be pulled straight in. Just the fact that it's a constant isn't enough, if it was a constant of type `Type`, it wouldn't work.

Comment: @biziclop: It wouldn't be a constant in JLS terminology in that case :) "A variable of primitive type or type String, that is final and initialized with a compile-time constant expression (§15.28), is called a constant variable."

Comment: @Jon didn't OP say that other classes are using parts of this library correctly at runtime?

Comment: @nsfyn55: I'd missed that bit - but I suspect it's not true :) (Alternatively, they may be using some older version or something like that.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, I'm sure this is exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the `Type` class on your runtime [classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html). You need to run the jar with `-cp` argument.

Answer (score 0):

What is that value of `type` when the runtime exception is thrown? if you read the java doc it `Converts a String representation of an Type into its numeric value`. It probably does this by instantiating it reflectively or some muck. If you run this method for a type string for which there is no associated `Type` I think its perfectly reasonable for you to get this error.

Step 1: print the string type and make sure a Class of that type is on the classpath.